# Recursively filling the height of a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have a homework problem that asks to write a method that recursively fills in the height of a binary search tree.

Below is my code

I checked the answer key for this problem and it made sense, but I wanted to know if my method is another valid way of doing this or not.

```
public static <T extends Comparable> void fillsHeight(BSTNode root){
        if (root == null) return;

        if (root.left == null && root.right == null) root.height = 0;

        if (root.left != null) height = root.left.height + 1;

        if (root.right != null) height = Math.max(height, root.right.height) + 1;


        fillsHeight(root.left);
        fillsHeight(root.right);

    }
```

And below is the official solution from the answer key:

```
 public static <T extends Comparable> 
   void fillHeights(BSTNode root) {
      if (root == null) { return; }
      fillHeights(root.left);
      fillHeights(root.right);
      root.height = -1;
      if (root.left != null) {
         root.height = root.left.height;
      }
      if (root.right != null) {
         root.height = Math.max(root.height, root.right.height);
      }
      root.height++;  
   }
```

Comment: If it passed all the test cases then yes . A solution can be implemented in 'N' number of ways. The answer we look is for time and space complexity

Answer (score 0):

The importance from the solution is that it first calls recursively to the root left and right subtree with `fillHeights(root.left);` and `fillHeights(root.right);`, and only **after that** compares the results.

You are also missing the vital part of actually adding to the height of the nodes, with `root.height++;`

Comment: i forgot to add +1 at the end of my answer's last 2 if statements.